# Возврат изображения на исходную activity при нажатии кнопки back

Tags: java, android

В приложении выбирается изображение ,которая отображается в ImageView и она затем передается на вторую Activity для изменения цвета. Затем нужно при нажатии back вернутся на первую Activity и чтоб там показывалось уже эта измененная картинка.Пожалуйста помогите с кодом.

MainActivity

```
Uri selectedImage;
ImageView preview;
Bitmap selectedphoto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button bCam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    bCam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            from_camera();

        }
    });

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            from_gallery();
        }
    });

    preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pass_another();
        }
    });


}
public void from_camera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 111);

}


public void from_gallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 222);
}

public void pass_another()
{
    String [] filePathColumn= {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    selectedphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    cursor.close();
    Intent data = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    data.putExtra("data", selectedphoto);
    data.setData(selectedImage);
    startActivity(data);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    selectedphoto   = null;
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 111) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        preview.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 222) {

        selectedImage = data.getData();
        preview.setImageURI(selectedImage);

    }

}
```

SecondActivity

```
Uri uri;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    uri=getIntent().getData();

    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.setSaturation(0);

    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    image.setColorFilter(filter);
    image.setImageURI(uri);



}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("data2",uri.toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: проблема в том, что ты не меняешь изображение. Ты просто накладываешь на ImageView ColorFilter. Тебе нужно либо меня само изображение и передавать обратно его, либо в первой активити так же накладывать  ColorFilter на ImageView

Comment: И как написать такой код? чтоб при возврате тоже накладывать?

Comment: ну так же как и во втором окне, берешь imageview нужное и делаешь ему setColorFilter.

Comment: preview.setColorFilter(filter)'

Comment: Это должно случится когда будем нажать на кнопку назад. я просто не понимаю как оттуда делать возврат. поможешь если не трудно?

Comment: Что написать в onBackPressed() и в MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

В `onBackPressed()` можете отправить настройки или фильтры для `ImageView` и в `Main Activity`, а именно в методе `onActivityResult()` применить эти фильтрыa

Comment: Можете в этот раз помочь мне и показать как это делать. я просто совсем новичок